# 1.button not displaying text 2. is logic correct

Tags: java, android, xml, button, if-statement

Question 1) For some reason, when i click "generate" it does not display any text.I want the button to do the following: after the user input 3 values (int) for example : 1,1,2 and click the "generate" button and the display message should be "Isosceles Triangle: 2 Congruent Sides"---this works before but my logic was wrong and I asked a question here : [If statement not working for android programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25956890/if-statement-not-working-for-android-programming) . then i try to implement the suggestions and now it has a different error

Question 2) Is my logic correct? Will I be able to display the correct result after fixing this problem?

Please help, I am new to android programming. Thanks so much in advance.

java code:

```
package com.example.trianglegame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TriangleGame extends Activity {// implement-have to use all of the
// methods
// set up the variables here

Button Gen;
EditText Input1;
EditText Input2;
EditText Input3;
String input1;
String input2;
String input3;

TextView Display;

int a;
int b;
int c;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);

    // assigning the values
    Input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Input3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    Display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);

    Gen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    Gen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // getting the text and converting it to string value
            input1 = Input1.getText().toString();
            input2 = Input2.getText().toString();
            input3 = Input2.getText().toString();

            // converting those text values back into int
            a = Integer.parseInt(input1);
            b = Integer.parseInt(input2);
            c = Integer.parseInt(input3);

            // displaying the message

            if ((a == b && b != c) || (a == c && b != c)
                    || (b == c && a != c)) {
                Display.setText("Isosceles Triangle: 2 Congruent Sides");
            } else if (a == b && a == c) {
                Display.setText("Equilateral Triangle:All sides are equal");
            }

            else if (a != b && a != c && b != c) {
                Display.setText("Scalene Triangle: No Congruent Sides");
            } else {
                Display.setText("Error");
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/enter_text" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/side_1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/type_hint"
    android:inputType="number" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/side_2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/type_hint"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/type_hint"
    android:text="@string/side_3" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/type_hint"
    android:inputType="number" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/generate" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/clear" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat Error

```
09-21 18:50:20.739: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
09-21 18:50:24.939: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
09-21 18:50:25.579: E/BatteryService(58): usbOnlinePath not found
09-21 18:50:25.579: E/BatteryService(58): batteryVoltagePath not found
09-21 18:50:25.579: E/BatteryService(58): batteryTemperaturePath not found
09-21 18:50:25.589: E/SurfaceFlinger(58): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or  /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
09-21 18:50:28.279: E/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
09-21 18:50:28.279: E/EventHub(58): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
09-21 18:50:28.379: E/System(58): Failure starting core service
09-21 18:50:28.379: E/System(58): java.lang.SecurityException
09-21 18:50:28.379: E/System(58):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
09-21 18:50:28.379: E/System(58):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
09-21 18:50:28.379: E/System(58):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
09-21 18:50:28.379: E/System(58):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
09-21 18:50:28.749: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
09-21 18:50:28.749: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
09-21 18:50:28.749: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
09-21 18:50:28.749: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
09-21 18:50:28.749: E/SoundPool(58): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
09-21 18:50:29.359: E/ThrottleService(58): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
09-21 18:50:29.819: E/logwrapper(133): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
09-21 18:50:29.889: E/logwrapper(135): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
09-21 18:50:29.889: E/logwrapper(136): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
09-21 18:50:32.957: E/HierarchicalStateMachine(58): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
```

Comment: what do you want to do on button click..please specify.

Comment: In Java and Android, your object and variable names must begin with lowercase, like `Button gen;`, unless they are `public static final`

Comment: hi, i changed the all of the input into lowercase but it's still not displaying the text after i click the generate button

Comment: what is your logcat showing???use system.out.println() in the button click to detect wheater the button click is fired

Comment: It's the path to the emulator. I adjusted it and everything works fine out. The main issue was that my button was covering my text, so the code and logic is fine. thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
input2 = Input2.getText().toString();
input3 = Input2.getText().toString();
```

use:

```
input2 = Input2.getText().toString();
input3 = Input3.getText().toString();
```

Comment: thanks for noticing that. I tried it but i still get the same error so it must be that and something else.

Comment: What is the output of 1,1,2?

Comment: At first it wasn't showing anything and it was because my button was covering it :) I know now, everything was fine except for the typo that you showed me. thanks again

Comment: good to know, coz i kept staring at your code failing to know what's wrong :D

Comment: hahah, I am new to this website so the questions I asked, I think others already asked and for some reason, my reputation points went down... hopefully I can still ask questions in the future. But yeah , i always research the questions and usually can't find an answer that's why I post it :)

Comment: you should spend some time reading the [best ways to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and similar topics.
If my answer is correct please don't forget to accept and upvote :)

Comment: I would love to but I can't upvote :) my reputation is too low, they don't allow me :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, logic is fine, although I would check in a different way, quite more readable.

```
int n = 0; //number of equal sides

if(a==b)
  n++;
if(a==c)
  n++;
if(b==c)
  n++;

//Display seems like a class, but is a variable, should start with lower case and have camel notation such as displayTextView
switch(n) {
  case 0:
    Display.setText("Scalen");
    break;
  case 1:
    Display.setText("Isosceles");
    break;
  case 2: case 3:
    Display.setText("Equilateral");
    break;
}
```

As far as the error it shows, could you post the log?

Comment: hi, when i was running the program, I do not see any error in the LogCat so I cannot post it :(

Comment: When the app crashes, if you have your phone connected, LogCat should print something, please try with IDE conencted

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. yes, it printed something now for errors. I will edit my post

Comment: I think that's not the log we're looking for haha, do you have the exception description? And just to be clear, your xml is game.xml?

Comment: yeah, it is game.xml . Hi, I did not throw in an exception for the input values. Was I suppose to do that? Do you suggest I look up on how to throw in exception for those input values?

Comment: No, exception should be thrown in runtime. Something like NullPointerException or OutOfBoundsIndexException... Idea is to know the line in your code is causing it.

Comment: LOL, nvm I got it, the buttons were covering the text. Everything works now :)

Comment: Haha ok, nice you found it